# Return index based on value for every value in pandas column

Tags: pandas

I am trying for an efficient way to pull the index of a value in a `pandas.DataFrame` or `.Series` object if it exists.

The application is to list the parent of a node given I know its children.

For example I have a dataframe `node_df` like so:

```
         child_node_id
node_id               
0                    1
1                    5
2                    3
3                   -1
4                    7
5                   -1
6                   -1
7                   -1
8                   -1
```

Node 0 has node 1 as its child node.
Node 1 has node 5 as its child node.
Node 2 has node 3 as its child node.
Node 4 has node 7 as its child node.

All other nodes have no children (`child_node_id == -1`).

I want the the `parent_node_id` such that:

```
         child_node_id  parent_node_id
node_id               
0                    1              -1
1                    5               0
2                    3               1
3                   -1               2
4                    7              -1
5                   -1               1
6                   -1              -1
7                   -1               4
8                   -1              -1
```

Right now, I use a loop

```
node_df['parent_node_id'] = -1
for ix, elem in node_df['child_node_id'].iteritems():
  node_df.loc[elem, 'parent_node_id'] = ix if elem >= -1 else -1
```

I was wondering if there was something more pandas-esque (akin to `list.index()` in Python) that could work without looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the answer is to use the child node's values as the index for the parent node column, while using the child node's index as the parent node's value.

```py
node_df['parent_node_id'] = -1
children = node_df.loc[node_df.child_node_id >= 0, 'child_node_id']
# child : (index, value):: parent : (value, index)
node_df.loc[children, 'parent_node_id'] = children.index
node_df['parent_node_id']
```